# Remove parent key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like remove key [Properties] from array like below

I have it:

```
Array(
 [Values] => 1
 [List] => Array(
     [Product] => Array( 
         [Details] => Array( 
            [Properties] => Array( 
                [Id] => 1
            )
         )
     )
  )
)
```

And I would like to remove [properties] :

```
Array(
  [Values] => 1
  [List] => Array(
    [Product] => Array( 
        [Details] => Array( 
            [ID] => 1
        )
     )
  )
)
```

I tried:

```
$result = array_map(function($sub) { return $sub['Properties']; }, $array);
```

and

```
$array= array_column($array, 'Properties');
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you edit your example input to show the structure when it has more than one entry?

Comment: use `unset()` as in `unset($myarray['properties'])`

Comment: @RobertRocha - it also doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight-forwardly:

```
$arr = [
    "Values" => 1,
    "List" => ["Product" => [ "Details" => ["Properties" => ["Id" => 1] ] ] ]
];

$arr['List']['Product']['Details']['Id'] = $arr['List']['Product']['Details']['Properties']['Id'];
unset($arr['List']['Product']['Details']['Properties']);

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Values] => 1
    [List] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [Details] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```