# Remove key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to delete key [Price] but the function which I use for deletion doesn't work for this case

I have:

```
Array(
       [Values] => 1
       [Product] => Array( 
                           [Details] => Array( 
                                              [ID] => 1
                                              [Price] => Array(
                                                              )
                                             )
                         )
    )
```

My goal is:

```
Array(
       [Values] => 1
       [Product] => Array( 
                           [Details] => Array( 
                                              [ID] => 1
                                             )
                         )
    )
```

I use this for removal:

```
function remove_key($array, $key)
        {
            foreach($array as $k => $v) {

                if(is_array($v)) {
                    $array[$k] = remove_key($v, $key);
                } elseif($k == $key) {
                    unset($array[$k]);
                }
            }
            return $array;
        }

$array = remove_key($array,'Price');
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove parent key in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410080/remove-parent-key-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Recursively unset array keys if match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708860/php-recursively-unset-array-keys-if-match)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    'Values' => 1,
 'Product' => Array(
    'Details' => Array(
        'id' => 1,
        'Price' => Array(
)
      )
   )
);



unset($array['Product']['Details']['Price']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

And the output is :

```
Array
(
    [Values] => 1
    [Product] => Array
        (
            [Details] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to fix your function you must add another condition into first `if` as so `&& $k != $key`
because you are not getting into `elseif` and `unset` is not called

```
  function remove_key($array, $key)
        {
            foreach($array as $k => $v) {
                if(is_array($v) && $k != $key) {
                    $array[$k] = remove_key($v, $key);
                } elseif($k == $key) {
                    unset($array[$k]);
                }
            }
            return $array;
        }
```